# With JSON.stringifyf how do I add square brackets?

Tags: jquery, json

I have code that produces a JSON string

```
{"did":50,"pid":"66","cid":"2","qty":1,"skus":{"ssid":"B931627", "type":"fab"
,"qty":1,"style":""}}
```

but I need to format it as

```
{"did":50,"pid":"66","cid":"2","qty":1,"skus":[{"ssid":"B931627", "type":"fab"
,"qty":1,"style":""}]}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
 var dataAttributes = {
   did : $(selector).data('did'),
   pid : $(selector).data('pid'),
   cid : $(selector).data('cid'),
   qty : '1',
   coveroptionskus : var ssus = {
         ssid : $(selector).data('ssid'),
         type : '',
         qty : 1,
         style : ''
       }
  };
```

Comment: skus should be an array that contains an object, in that case.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: `obj['skus'] = [{ssid:....}];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `""` double quotes around `dataAttributes` property names , values

```
 var dataAttributes = {
   "did" : $(selector).data("did"),
   "pid" : $(selector).data("pid"),
   "cid" : $(selector).data("cid"),
   "qty" : "1",
   // removed `var`
   // set as `skus` property as `Array`,
   // set properties of object
   // within `skus` array
   "skus" : [{
             "ssid" : $(selector).data("ssid"),
             "type" : "",
             "qty" : 1,
             "style" : ""
            }]
  };
  // call `JSON.stringify()` with `dataAttributes` as parameter 
  JSON.stringify(dataAttributes);
```